# MacOS cmake fails to find_package(OpenGL)

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, cmake

At some point cmake stopped finding OpenGL with this error message

`Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR)`

Then I set `CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE` to true, and then I realized that cmake is not looking in the frameworks folder

`message("${CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH}")` prints empty string

After setting `CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH` to `/System/Library/Frameworks` cmake still fails to find OpenGL

`Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR)`

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. Why CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH is an empty string (should it be?)
2. Why CMake does not find OpenGL headers even if I specify the frameworks folder

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to call find_package before project in my CMakeLists.txt

reordering lines of code in this way:

```
project("name")
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
```

solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH is an empty string (should it be?)

Generally, yes, it should be empty. You'd only set `CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH` if you've installed a framework in a non-standard location.

> Why CMake does not find OpenGL headers even if I specify the frameworks folder

Well, `/System/Library/Frameworks` isn't where the headers are. They're in SDK you're targeting, and for that you'll need XCode or the command-line tools installed.

```console
$ find /System/Library/Frameworks/ -name gl.h
$ find /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/ -name gl.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk//System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/gl.h
```

With a basic `CMakeLists.txt`

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.0 FATAL_ERROR)
include(CMakePrintHelpers)
project(t)

cmake_print_variables(OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY)
cmake_print_variables(OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR)
cmake_print_variables(CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH)
find_package(OpenGL)
cmake_print_variables(OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY)
cmake_print_variables(OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR)
cmake_print_variables(CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH)
```

you get:

```console
$ rm -rf CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles/; cmake --version ; cmake .
cmake version 3.27.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY=""
-- OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR=""
-- CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH=""
-- Found OpenGL: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
-- OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework"
-- OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework"
-- CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH=""
-- Configuring done (0.5s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp

$
```

Comment: So, the problem with cmake not finding opengl is that the installation broken after some actions? Should I reinstall command line tools to fix the problem?